# How i can get uid in firebase db?

Tags: java, database, firebase-realtime-database

I trying to read data from db and i trying to read like usiing this childs:

```
child("User").child(emaildb).
```

But how i can get name of this child:
[image]
this child created automatly after pushing data into db.
How i use this code to try read data:

```java
load.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        String a = emailString.replace(".", "");
        Query recentPostsQuery = database.child("User").child(firebaseUser.getUid()).child(a);
        recentPostsQuery.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                for (DataSnapshot snapshot : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                    User value = dataSnapshot.getValue(User.class);
                    Toast.makeText(More.this, "User-loaded data", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                    PreferenceConfig.Data(getApplicationContext(), data);
```

Comment: None of the code in your question is reading anything from the Firebase Realtime Database yet, so it's hard to say what isn't working about it. Can you edit your question to show a [minimal repro](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) (read the link please, it's quite useful)?

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen, is this anought?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code tries to read `database.child("User").child(firebaseUser.getUid())`, but the key under the `User` node is not a UID. That explains why the code can't find the data.

If you want to be able to look up the user by their UID, you should first store the data under the UID of the user. It look like currently you do something like:

```
ref.child("User").push().setValue(userdata);
```

The `push()` call in here creates the `-NP` key. To store the data under the user's UID, you'll want to do:

```
String uid = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser().getUid();

ref.child("User").child(uid).setValue(userdata);
```

Comment: Can i push data without uid of user?

Comment: That's what you did. But then you can't load the data based on the UID, because nothing in the screenshot you shared allows the database to map from the UID of the user to the node you have in there.

Comment: Well.. I use auth only to create acount and i put email in SharedPreferences which don't have points, create variable for this email and i push it to db. When i get data using "new" email like for child. Is it incorrect?

Comment: Once you create an account, the user gets a UID. So at that point you can use the code in my answer to create their profile in Firestore, and after that your code for reading their profile will worj.

Comment: Every time when i prees btn for pushing data, database creates own id, can i decline your offer and use childs without uid?

Comment: Your code for **reading** the user is doing database.child("User").child(firebaseUser.getUid())` - so it assumed you've stored the data under a UID. You can do whatever you want, but the code that reads and the code that writes will have to match up.